Alternative methods for testing Laravel job dispatching in unit tests
I'm writing unit tests for a job's login functionality in Laravel. However, when I attempted to dispatch the job using Job::dispatchSync, it seems that the job wasn't executed.
Upon further investigation, I found that dispatchSync dispatches the job on a sync queue. I'm unsure why it's implemented this way, but I need a method to dispatch the job manually within my unit tests.
Unfortunately, I can't use dispatchNow on the job because it's unavailable in the Dispatchable trait. I could manually call the handle function on the job class, but I'd not resort to this method instead.
Are there any alternative ways to test the logic within job classes? I am using a job structured as:
class ProcessWebhook implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct(private $payload)
    {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info("job constructor");
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(Service $service)
    {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info("job is handled");
    }
}

and to test this job I am writing unit tests as
public function test_job($payload): void
{
    ProcessWebhook::dispatchSync($client, $payload);

    // make assertions
}

According to this code snippet, in Logs, I am getting the constructor message but not the handled message. While using dispatchSync, the job is not called at all by the' handle' method. Using:
(new ProcessWebhook($payload))->handle(app(Service::class));

works fine.

"not being executed at all" - That doesn't sound right. "I'm unsure of the reasoning behind this implementation" - The sync driver for queues is simply executing the queue as a foreground task (in the same process that is running Job::dispatchSync) instead of a background task (i.e. a different process, like a queue listener). I've never personally tested jobs, but wouldn't you want them to run in the same process as the test to actually test them? Maybe edit your question with a functional example, like a Job and it's associated test.

I don't understand your issue... Job::dispatchSync will dispatch it as sync because it is in the name... what is the issue of it not being dispatch to sync? It must be dispatched to sync, else how can you test it? I do not understand your question/issue
